# NSUserDefaults not working ... or is it me?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, ios5

So I am trying to pass a url between views. I was thinking that the following code will stomp on whatever is in @"url" every time the user makes a selection from the tableview. What actually happens is that the first selection is always being returned and is never stomped on. Hmmmm, maybe it is me? Any ideas? Thanks.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        [self saveToUserDefaults:@"http://url1"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.webController animated:YES];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        [self saveToUserDefaults:@"http://url2"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.webController animated:YES];
    }
}

-(void)saveToUserDefaults:(NSString*)myString
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (standardUserDefaults) 
    {
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:myString forKey:@"url"];
        [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
    }
}
```

On the receiving end:

```
-(NSString*)retrieveFromUserDefaults
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *val = nil;

    if (standardUserDefaults) 
        val = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"url"];

    return val;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    NSString *url = self.retrieveFromUserDefaults;
    [self handleURLRequest:url];
}
```

Comment: I wonder is it a case that NSUserDefaults is saving in an async thread (as part of its internal implementation) and that the push'd viewController is re-reading the value too fast for the write. Put in a small delay or performSelector:WithDelay: between the save operation and the push to just make sure.

Comment: Have you logged myString right before [standardUserDefaults setObject:myString forKey:@"url"]?

Comment: ummmm .... i am the newbie and I have no idea what you are talking about. I added the receiving code for review. Maybe the problem is there.

Comment: Hmm.. I was thinking ... I am calling retrieveFromUserDefaults in view did load. Does that get called every time I select an item from the previous table?

Comment: See 2nd part of my edited answer below...

Comment: re: view did load .... ah, that changes everything! see @jrtuton's answer below ... that's what you want to do!

Comment: BTW, there is easier ways of passing the URL to the pushed view controller. Just saying :-)

Comment: I am always interested in learning easier ways to pass irks. What is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is only called when your view is initially loaded from the xib file. If you pop and re-push the view controller then the method won't be executed again unless you've received low memory warnings.

Move the code to `viewWillAppear` which is guarantee to be called every time your view, well, appears.

Answer (score 1):

Your code for saving the NSString to NSUserDefaults looks correct and should overwrite any value already saved for the "url" key. Perhaps there is an error in the way you are reading this value in the other view? Could you post your code from the next view controller?

Based on your new code, if you are keeping the 2nd view controller around, you may need to put your code in viewWillAppear rather than viewDidLoad.

Comment: Why are you using self.retrieveFromUserDefaults rather than [self retrieveFromUserDefaults]?